# transform a dataframe with frozenset values to plain dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, frozenset

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    antecedents    consequents          support    confidence      lift
0   (weather1)   (go for swimming)     0.965517      1.0          1.035714
1   (weather2)   (stay home)          0.965517       1.0          1.035714
```

The dataframe has frozenset values. For example:

```
df['antecedents'][0]

frozenset({weather1})
```

How to transform this dataframe to a plain dataframe (i.e without frozenset values)?

I tried to transform to a list and back to a dataframe but this is not working

Any ideas?

Comment: is the weather1 string over there

Comment: What code have you tried, and why did it not work?